problems with telegram bot

async def tasks_menu(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    telegram_id = update.message.from_user.id
    user = get_user(telegram_id)
    if not user:
        await update.message.reply_text("Пользователь не найден.")
        return

    completed_task_ids = [task['task_id'] for task in get_user_tasks(user_id=user['id'])]

    tasks = get_tasks()
    if not tasks:
        await update.message.reply_text("Нет доступных заданий.")
        return

    user_role = user.get('role')
    social_preferences = user.get('social_responses', {})
    if isinstance(social_preferences, str):
        social_preferences = json.loads(social_preferences)
    preferred_social_networks = [key for key, value in social_preferences.items() if value.lower() == 'да']

    filtered_tasks = [
        task for task in tasks
        if task['role'] == user_role and task['social_network'] in preferred_social_networks and task['id'] not in completed_task_ids
    ]

    if not filtered_tasks:
        await update.message.reply_text("Нет доступных заданий для вас.")
        return

    page = context.user_data.get('tasks_page', 0)
    items_per_page = 5
    start_idx = page * items_per_page
    end_idx = start_idx + items_per_page
    task_buttons = [[InlineKeyboardButton(task['description'], callback_data=f"task_{task['id']}")] for task in filtered_tasks[start_idx:end_idx]]

    if start_idx > 0:
        task_buttons.append([InlineKeyboardButton("Previous", callback_data="tasks_prev")])
    if end_idx < len(filtered_tasks):
        task_buttons.append([InlineKeyboardButton("Next", callback_data="tasks_next")])

    if update.callback_query:
        await update.callback_query.message.reply_text("Доступные задания:", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(task_buttons))
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text("Доступные задания:", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(task_buttons))

async def support(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    telegram_id = update.message.from_user.id
    SUPPORT_CONTEXT[telegram_id] = True
    await update.message.reply_text("Напишите ваш вопрос, и наша поддержка свяжется с вами.")

async def handle_support_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    telegram_id = update.message.from_user.id
    if SUPPORT_CONTEXT.get(telegram_id):
        username = update.message.from_user.username
        question = update.message.text
        add_support_message(telegram_id, username, question)
        await update.message.reply_text("Ваш запрос в поддержку принят. Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время.")
        SUPPORT_CONTEXT.pop(telegram_id, None)
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text("Команда не распознана. Используйте доступные команды.")

async def withdraw_info(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    telegram_id = update.message.from_user.id
    completed_tasks = get_completed_tasks(telegram_id)
    if completed_tasks < 2:
        await update.message.reply_text("Чтобы вывести средства вам понадобится выполнить пару заданий, после кнопка вывода средств появится у вас в этом меню")
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text("Вы можете вывести средства. Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с поддержкой для деталей.")

async def withdraw_balance(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    await update.message.reply_text("Введите ID пользователя и сумму для вывода (например, '12345 10.00').")
    return WITHDRAW_AMOUNT

async def handle_withdraw_amount(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    try:
        telegram_id = update.message.from_user.id
        username = update.message.from_user.username
        user_input = update.message.text.split()
        user_id = int(user_input[0])
        amount = float(user_input[1])
        message = f"Запрос на вывод средств: {user_id} {amount:.2f}$"
        add_support_message(telegram_id, username, message)
        await update.message.reply_text("Ваш запрос на вывод средств отправлен в поддержку.")
    except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError):
        await update.message.reply_text("Неверный формат ввода. Пожалуйста, используйте формат '12345 10.00'.")
    return ConversationHandler.END

async def task_submission(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    telegram_id = update.message.from_user.id
    photo = update.message.photo[-1]
    photo_file = await photo.get_file()
    screenshot_url = photo_file.file_path

    current_task_id = context.user_data.get('current_task_id')
    if not current_task_id:
        await update.message.reply_text("У вас нет активных заданий.")
        return

    assign_task(telegram_id, current_task_id, screenshot_url, 'submitted')
    await update.message.reply_text("Ваше задание отправлено на проверку.")

async def profile(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    telegram_id = update.message.from_user.id
    user = get_user(telegram_id)
    if not user:
        await update.message.reply_text("Пользователь не найден.")
        return

    completed_tasks = get_completed_tasks(telegram_id)
    total_earnings = calculate_total_earnings(telegram_id)
    balance = get_user_balance(telegram_id)

    text = (f"Ваш профиль:\n"
            f"ID: {telegram_id}\n"
            f"Выполнил заданий: {completed_tasks}\n"
            f"Заработал за всё время: ${total_earnings:.2f}\n"
            f"Баланс: ${balance:.2f}")

    await update.message.reply_text(text)

async def admin_support(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    support_messages = get_support_messages()
    if not support_messages:
        await query.message.reply_text("Нет новых сообщений поддержки.")
        return

    for message in support_messages:
        text = (f"Сообщение от @{message['username']}\n"
                f"Вопрос: {message['question']}")
        buttons = [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Ответить", callback_data=f"answer_{message['id']}"),
        ]
        await query.message.reply_text(text, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([buttons]))

async def admin_tasks(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    user_tasks = get_user_tasks()
    if not user_tasks:
        await query.message.reply_text("Нет новых заданий на проверку.")
        return

    for task in user_tasks:
        text = (f"Задание от @{task['username']}\n"
                f"Задание: {task['description']}\n"
                f"Скриншот: {task['screenshot_url']}")
        buttons = [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Одобрить", callback_data=f"approve_task_{task['id']}"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Отклонить", callback_data=f"reject_task_{task['id']}")
        ]
        await query.message.reply_text(text, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([buttons]))

async def handle_task_callback(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    logger.info(f"Callback data: {query.data}")

    try:
        if query.data.startswith('approve_task_'):
            task_id = int(query.data.split('_')[-1])
            update_task_status(task_id, 'approved')
            task = get_task(task_id)
            if task and task.get('telegram_id'):
                user = get_user(task['telegram_id'])
                if user:
                    reward = task['reward']
                    update_user_balance(user['telegram_id'], reward)
                    await query.message.reply_text(f"Задание {task_id} одобрено.")
                    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=user['telegram_id'], text="Ваше задание одобрено! Теперь вы можете использовать бота для выполнения заданий.")
                else:
                    logger.error(f"User with ID {task['telegram_id']} not found.")
                    await query.message.reply_text(f"Ошибка: пользователь с ID {task['telegram_id']} не найден.")
            else:
                logger.error(f"'telegram_id' not found in task {task}")
                await query.message.reply_text(f"Ошибка: 'telegram_id' не найдено в задании {task_id}.")
        elif query.data.startswith('reject_task_'):
            task_id = int(query.data.split('_')[-1])
            update_task_status(task_id, 'rejected')
            task = get_task(task_id)
            await query.message.reply_text(f"Задание {task_id} отклонено.")
            if task and task.get('telegram_id'):
                user = get_user(task['telegram_id'])
                if user:
                    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=user['telegram_id'], text="Ваше задание отклонено. Попробуйте снова позже.")
                else:
                    logger.error(f"User with ID {task['telegram_id']} not found.")
            else:
                logger.error(f"'telegram_id' not found in task {task}")
        elif query.data.startswith('task_'):
            task_id = int(query.data.split('_')[-1])
            task = get_task(task_id)
            context.user_data['current_task_id'] = task_id
            await query.message.reply_text(f"Вы выбрали задание: {task['description']}. Ссылка на задание: {task['url']}. Пожалуйста, отправьте скриншот для подтверждения.")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error handling task callback: {e}")
        await query.message.reply_text(f"Произошла ошибка при обработке задания: {e}")

async def handle_support_callback(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    if query.data.startswith('answer_'):
        message_id = int(query.data.split('_')[1])
        context.user_data['support_message_id'] = message_id
        await query.message.reply_text("Введите ваш ответ на запрос поддержки:")
        return ANSWER_SUPPORT_MESSAGE
    elif query.data.startswith('support_reply_'):
        user_id = int(query.data.split('_')[2])
        context.user_data['support_reply_user_id'] = user_id
        await query.message.reply_text("Введите ваш ответ:")
        return SUPPORT_REPLY

async def answer_support_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    response = update.message.text
    message_id = context.user_data.get('support_message_id')
    support_message = get_support_message_by_id(message_id)
    update_support_response(message_id, response)
    await send_admin_response(support_message['telegram_id'], response, context)
    await update.message.reply_text("Ответ отправлен пользователю.")
    return ConversationHandler.END

async def add_task_description(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    query = update.callback_query
    if query:
        await query.answer()
        await query.edit_message_text(text="Введите название задания:")
        return 'ADD_TASK_DESCRIPTION'
    else:
        TASK_CREATION['description'] = update.message.text
        await update.message.reply_text("Введите ссылку на задание:")
        return 'ADD_TASK_URL'

async def add_task_url(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    TASK_CREATION['url'] = update.message.text
    await update.message.reply_text("Выберите соц сеть:", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup([
        ["tiktok", "youtube_shorts", "instagram_reels", "likee", "vk_clips"]
    ], one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True))
    return 'ADD_TASK_SOCIAL_NETWORK'

async def add_task_social_network(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    TASK_CREATION['social_network'] = update.message.text
    await update.message.reply_text("Введите роль (support/creator):")
    return 'ADD_TASK_ROLE'

async def add_task_role(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    TASK_CREATION['role'] = update.message.text
    await update.message.reply_text("Введите вознаграждение за задание:")
    return 'ADD_TASK_REWARD'

async def add_task_reward(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    try:
        reward = float(update.message.text)
        TASK_CREATION['reward'] = reward
    except ValueError:
        await update.message.reply_text("Неверный формат вознаграждения. Пожалуйста, введите числовое значение.")
        return 'ADD_TASK_REWARD'
    
    await update.message.reply_text("Введите количество выполнений:")
    return 'ADD_TASK_QUANTITY'

async def add_task_quantity(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    TASK_CREATION['quantity'] = update.message.text
    await confirm_task_creation(update, context)
    return 'CONFIRM_TASK_CREATION'

async def confirm_task_creation(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    task_description = TASK_CREATION.get('description', '')
    task_url = TASK_CREATION.get('url', '')
    task_social_network = TASK_CREATION.get('social_network', '')
    task_role = TASK_CREATION.get('role', '')
    task_reward = TASK_CREATION.get('reward', '')
    task_quantity = TASK_CREATION.get('quantity', '')
    telegram_id = update.message.from_user.id if update.message else update.callback_query.from_user.id

    await update.message.reply_text(
        f"Пожалуйста, подтвердите детали задания:\n\n"
        f"Название: {task_description}\n"
        f"Ссылка: {task_url}\n"
        f"Социальная сеть: {task_social_network}\n"
        f"Роль: {task_role}\n"
        f"Вознаграждение: {task_reward}\n"
        f"Количество: {task_quantity}\n\n"
        f"Если все верно, подтвердите создание задания.",
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Подтвердить", callback_data='confirm_task')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Отменить", callback_data='cancel_task')]
        ])
    )
    return 'CONFIRM_TASK_CREATION'

async def confirm_task(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()

    try:
        reward = float(TASK_CREATION['reward'])
    except ValueError:
        await query.message.edit_text("Неверный формат вознаграждения. Пожалуйста, введите числовое значение.")
        return ConversationHandler.END

    add_task(
        TASK_CREATION['description'],
        TASK_CREATION['url'],
        TASK_CREATION['role'],
        TASK_CREATION['social_network'],
        reward,
        TASK_CREATION['quantity'],
        query.from_user.id
    )
    await query.message.edit_text("Задание успешно добавлено.")
    return ConversationHandler.END

async def cancel_task(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()

    await query.message.edit_text("Создание задания отменено.")
    return ConversationHandler.END

async def faq(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    faqs = get_faq()
    if not faqs:
        await update.message.reply_text("Нет доступных FAQ.")
        return

    buttons = [[InlineKeyboardButton(faq['question'], callback_data=f"faq_{faq['id']}")] for faq in faqs]
    await update.message.reply_text("FAQ:", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons))

async def handle_faq_callback(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    if query.data.startswith('faq_'):
        faq_id = int(query.data.split('_')[1])
        faq = get_faq(faq_id=faq_id)
        if faq:
            await query.message.edit_text(f"Вопрос: {faq['question']}\n\nОтвет: {faq['answer']}")
        else:
            await query.message.edit_text("FAQ не найден.")

async def admin_faq(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    if not is_admin(query.from_user.id):
        await query.message.reply_text(" У вас нет доступа к этой команде.")
        return

    faqs = get_faq()
    buttons = [[InlineKeyboardButton(faq['question'], callback_data=f"edit_faq_{faq['id']}")] for faq in faqs]
    buttons.append([InlineKeyboardButton("Добавить FAQ", callback_data="add_faq")])
    await query.message.reply_text("FAQ управление:", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons))

async def add_faq_question(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    query = update.callback_query
    if query:
        await query.answer()
        await query.edit_message_text(text="Введите текст вопроса для FAQ:")
        return 'ADD_FAQ_QUESTION'
    else:
        context.user_data['faq_question'] = update.message.text
        await update.message.reply_text("Введите текст ответа для FAQ:")
        return 'ADD_FAQ_ANSWER'

async def add_faq_answer(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    faq_question = context.user_data.get('faq_question')
    faq_answer = update.message.text

    add_faq(faq_question, faq_answer)
    await update.message.reply_text("FAQ успешно добавлен.")
    return ConversationHandler.END

async def edit_faq_answer(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> str:
    faq_id = context.user_data.get('edit_faq_id')
    faq_answer = update.message.text

    update_faq(faq_id, faq_answer)
    await update.message.reply_text("FAQ успешно обновлен.")
    return ConversationHandler.END

async def add_admin_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if not is_admin(update.message.from_user.id):
        await update.message.reply_text(" У вас нет доступа к этой команде.")
        return

    try:
        new_admin_id = int(update.message.text.split()[1])
        add_admin(new_admin_id)
        await update.message.reply_text(f"Пользователь {new_admin_id} добавлен как администратор.")
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        await update.message.reply_text("Использование: /add_admin <user_id>")

async def remove_admin_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if not is_admin(update.message.from_user.id):
        await update.message.reply_text(" У вас нет доступа к этой команде.")
        return

    try:
        admin_id = int(update.message.text.split()[1])
        remove_admin(admin_id)
        await update.message.reply_text(f"Пользователь {admin_id} удален из администраторов.")
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        await update.message.reply_text("Использование: /remove_admin <user_id>")

async def withdraw_balance(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if not is_admin(update.message.from_user.id):
        await update.message.reply_text(" У вас нет доступа к этой команде.")
        return

    await update.message.reply_text("Введите ID пользователя и сумму для вывода (например, '12345 10.00').")
    return WITHDRAW_AMOUNT

async def handle_withdraw_amount(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if not is_admin(update.message.from_user.id):
        await update.message.reply_text(" У вас нет доступа к этой команде.")
        return ConversationHandler.END

    try:
        telegram_id, amount = update.message.text.split()
        telegram_id = int(telegram_id)
        amount = float(amount)
        update_user_balance(telegram_id, -amount)
        await update.message.reply_text(f"Вывод средств для пользователя {telegram_id} на сумму {amount:.2f} выполнен.")
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        await update.message.reply_text("Неверный формат ввода. Пожалуйста, используйте формат '12345 10.00'.")
    return ConversationHandler.END

async def send_admin_response(telegram_id: int, response: str, context: CallbackContext):
    buttons = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Ответить", callback_data=f'support_reply_{telegram_id}')]
    ]
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=telegram_id, text=f"Ответ на ваш запрос: {response}", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons))

def ignore_non_commands(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    if update.message.text.startswith('/'):
        return

async def edit_questions(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()

    questions = get_survey_questions()
    buttons = [[InlineKeyboardButton(question['question'], callback_data=f"edit_{question['step']}")] for question in questions]
    await query.message.reply_text("Выберите вопрос для редактирования:", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons))
    return 'EDIT_QUESTION'

async def update_question(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    
    logger.info(f"Received callback query data: {query.data}")

    question_step = int(query.data.split('_')[1])
    context.user_data['editing_question_step'] = question_step

    question_data = get_survey_question(question_step)
    await query.message.reply_text(f"Текущий текст вопроса:\n{question_data['question']}\n\nВведите новый текст:")
    return 'SAVE_QUESTION'

async def save_question(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    new_text = update.message.text
    question_step = context.user_data.get('editing_question_step')

    if question_step is not None:
        update_survey_question(question_step, new_text)
        await update.message.reply_text("Вопрос успешно обновлен.")
    return ConversationHandler.END

async def withdraw_balance(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if not is_admin(update.message.from_user.id):
        await update.message.reply_text(" У вас нет доступа к этой команде.")
        return

    await update.message.reply_text("Введите ID пользователя и сумму для вывода (например, '12345 10.00').")
    return WITHDRAW_AMOUNT

async def handle_withdraw_amount(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if not is_admin(update.message.from_user.id):
        await update.message.reply_text(" У вас нет доступа к этой команде.")
        return ConversationHandler.END

I've tried different methods, different connections. But nothing solved my problem, as the packages do not connect, they write
"CommandHandler" is not accessedPylance
the same goes for CallbackQueryHandler Message Handler filters, although I've connected everything

What exactly is the problem? Please describe your issue in a meaningful way that can be used to reproduce the issue locally
